# How to get local time in moment.js on Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, utc

Using js library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

My local time is now: **05:32 AM**

After calling `moment()` I get:

Chrome:

`{..._isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale, _d: Sun Jan 22 2017 05:32:50 GMT+0100 (CET)…}`

Firefox

`{..._isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2017-01-22T04:32:50.515Z}`

Firefox moment points at **4 AM**, while Chrome points at **5 AM**.

How do I get local time in Firefox by using moment.js to have consistent result?

Comment: It's the same time; it's only the timezones of the formatted representation of the time that differ. Chrome's is in GMT+0100 and Firefox's is in GMT/UTC.

Comment: @cartant Ah, thanks. It is my first time working with time. I missinterpreted the result.